# Link Error while accessing Function defined inside a namespace of a different project

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2013, visual-c++-6

> error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: __thiscall

I have a project which has -
- ProjectA.h
- ProjectA.cpp
- Other files
`ProjectA.h` has a `namespace` that defines a function signature as

```
namespace someNamespace {
    class someClass {
        someClass();
        someFunction();
    };
}
```

I have a testProject which calls into `someFunction()` to see the result for the given test cases. I'm using VC6 to compile the `ProjectA` stuff and the test program is compiled in Visual Studio 2013.

- I have included all header files as VC++ includes
- I included the debug lib folder as linker addition.

Edit: As mentioned in the comments, i **guess** it might not be possible to use library compiled in VC6 to VC2013.

Comment: *I included the debug lib folder as linker addition* well you also need to add the actual *library* as linker input, not just point it to the directory where it can find that library

Comment: Yeah i'm sorry about that, but yes i did add the .lib i needed

Comment: You can't take a library compiled with VC6 and expect it work with VS2013.  You need to build both ProjectA and testProject with the same compiler version.